# Take all Cells from row until column 31, then loop to next row

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a macro that takes cells from one row (incrementing the cell taken by 2 each time) then paste it into another spreadsheet until it hits column 33, then start on the next row.

[image]

Return This
[image]

Based upon my code so far, it returns the values like this : [image]

```
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim shtDest As Worksheet   
Dim cell As Integer
Dim cellnum As Integer
Dim cellhours As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer                 
cellhours = 3
cellnum = 10
lastrow = 8

            Do Until cellnum > 31
                
                ' STHours
                If Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, cellnum).Value Like "Reg*" Or Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, cellnum).Value Like "*OffReg*" Or Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, cellnum).Value Like "*Hol*" Then
                
                    shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, cellhours).Value + shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value
                    
                'OTHours
                Else
                    
                    shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 11).Value = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, cellhours).Value + shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value

                End If

                
                destLRow = destLRow + 1
                cellhours = cellhours + 3
                cellnum = cellnum + 3
                lastrow = lastrow + 1
            Loop
```

Comment: there's probably an easier way to go about it: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-every-nth-column

Comment: @sous2817 normally I would agree with you. Unfortunately this process is setup within a much larger VBA macro and needs to be implemented through vba and not excel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it! Sorry I'm new to VBA so Im sure this code looks awful lol. But here it is.

```
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim destLRow As Integer
Dim cell As Integer
Dim cellnum As Integer
Dim cellhours As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rownum As Integer
  cellhours = 8
  cellnum = 10
  lastrow = 8
  rownum = 2
    
    'amount of people
        For person = 1 To lRow
    
            Do Until cellnum > 31
                
                ' STHours
                If Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(rownum, cellnum).Value Like "Reg*" Or Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(rownum, cellnum).Value Like "*OffReg*" Or Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(rownum, cellnum).Value Like "*Hol*" Then
                
                    shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(rownum, cellhours).Value + shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value
                    
                'OTHours
                Else
                    
                    shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 11).Value = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(rownum, cellhours).Value + shtDest.Cells(lastrow, 10).Value

                End If


                cellhours = cellhours + 3
                cellnum = cellnum + 3
                
            Loop
            lastrow = lastrow + 1
            rownum = rownum + 1
            cellnum = 10
            cellhours = 8
        Next person
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. Also you can make your code a little bit more easy. You can run your for loop with the parameter "step". Its a way to skip 1 column.